# Adding a white circle to an image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, draw

im using python 3.7.4, im trying to add to an image a white circle, but im inable to add the color white.
this is my code so far:(i already made a certain image)

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
def ima(n,m):
    what=Image.new(mode='L', size=(n,n), color=m)
    mat=what.load()
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            mat[x,y]=x%256
    return what
image=surprise(200,255) #my random image
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
image=ima(200,255)
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse([(50,50),(190,245)],fill='white',outline='white') #i want the fill to be white,i tried writing None, it did not give me a white circle.(a circle of a differnet color)
plt.show(block=image)
imageplot=plt.imshow(image)
```

Comment: Note that `Image.new(mode='L', ...` creates a black&white image with 256 grey values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ima(n,m):
    """Create and return an nxn gradient image"""
    what=Image.new(mode='L', size=(n,n), color=m)
    mat=what.load()
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            mat[x,y]=x%256
    return what

# Create image 200x200
image=ima(200,255)

# Get drawing handle
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.ellipse([(50,50),(190,245)],fill='white',outline='white')

# Display result
image.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the command image.show() shows AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'show'. i used instead imageplot=plt.imshow(image) and plt.show(block=image), how do i use image.show()?

Comment: Ok, try saving it in the current directory with `image.save('result.png')` and view it afterwards. What OS are you on?

Comment: @Mary You need `plt.imshow(image, cmap='Greys_r')` followed by `plt.show()` to display the image using the "correct" grey values.

Comment: `plt.show(block=True)` means that the program should be blocked so the user can interact with the image (e.g. zooming). The program continues as soon as the user closes the plot window.  `plt.show(block=False)` displays the image without interaction, and closes the plot automatically when the program ends (which is immediately in this example code).

Comment: i tried again (without image.save),and it worked! thanks alot!

Comment: @JohanC Thanks for lending a hand - I don't normally use Matplotlib as I find PIL's `im.show()` a lot simpler!

Comment: Matplotlib and PIL live in different worlds. Trying to mix them can lead to a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `imshow` of matplotlib you can specify a colormap (`cmap`) argument, if you don't matplotlib will be using a default colormap which might not be what you expect. You can see what colormap is being used by using `plt.colorbar()`. See my revised code for some examples. See also the [matplotlib colormap documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def ima(n,m):
    what=Image.new(mode='L', size=(n,n), color=m)
    mat=what.load()
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            mat[x,y]=x%256
    return what

image=ima(200,255)
draw=ImageDraw.Draw(image)

draw.ellipse([(50,50),(190,245)], fill='white', outline='white') 

plt.close('all')

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image) # <-- matplotlib using it's default color translation
plt.colorbar()

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image, cmap='Greys')
plt.colorbar()

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Note that appending "_r" to a colormap name gives the name of the reversed colormap. So you can use "Greys_r" to show the circle in white. Other possibilities for colormaps are e.g. "bone",  "copper" or "pink", depending on the intended use of the grey scale image.